# iOS Firebase get data where value equals to something

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get data in swift3 from firebase where the value equals something.

In MySQL that would be `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE type = 'brown'";` how can I write that `where` part in Firebase?

I have this DB

[image]

And I want to get all the data from it where `month` == `currentMonth` (I have a `currentMonth` variable)

Answer (score 3):

You can `Query` like this:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("Budget")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "Month")
    .queryEqual(toValue: "November")
    .observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

        var array:[Budget] = []

        for budgetChild in snapshot.children {
            let budgetSnapshot = budgetChild as! DataSnapshot
            let budgetDictionary = budgetSnapshot.value as! [String:String]

            let budget: Budget = Budget()
            budget.description_ = budgetDictionary["Description"]
            budget.month = budgetDictionary["Month"]
            budget.type = budgetDictionary["Type"]
            budget.value = budgetDictionary["Value"]

            array.append(budget)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware firebase realtime database doesn't have support for querying like this.  Instead you need to call down the whole ref 'budget' then filter it locally in your app.

FireStore apparently has better query support although its in Beta.